# Anonymous new line character appending when writing to file using fs.writeFileSync()

Tags: json, node.js, fs

I am sending an ajax to a node js server and iterating for loop write values in files using fs.writeFileSync(), but a new line character(\n) gets appended anomalously.

[InputFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUFmc.png)

Input form:-

and sending the contents as a json

```
var inputs = $('#input').val();
inputs = inputs.split(",\n");
inputs = JSON.stringify(inputs);

$.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost:5000',
        method: "POST",
        data:{
              input: inputs
              }
      })
```

and at node end

```
var inputs = req.body.input;
inputs = JSON.parse(inputs);
var i = "";
inputs.forEach(function(elem){
   elem = elem.trim();
   i =inputs.indexOf(elem);
   fs.writeFileSync("/inputFile"+i,elem)
   console.log("Input"+i+" file was saved!");                     
});
```

But the out I get written in my file is inputFile0 => 56\n, inputFile1 => 4444\n, inputFile2 => 57\n.

I don't know how to get data written without this newline character.

[OutputFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxXbs.png)

Comment: do you get **56\n** newline escape character in file

Comment: yes let me include a screenshot of it

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/HOb3Vs2 I did this n i don't get **/n**

Comment: dont know bro from whr it i coming

Comment: try to log *elem* and see what is in it.

Comment: ok i got some info i am changing permission of the file and thts the thing which adds a \n exec("chmod 777 \'"+Execute.path+Execute.folder+"/inputFile"+i+"\'");

Comment: I dont think that is the prob

Comment: den??? what u think

Comment: this is weird as it works on my system but it added '/n' in yours

Comment: can you pls approve my edit